# Why does this closure not execute on every element of the int range?

Tags: groovy

Here is my code:

```
def myclosey = {items -> 
    items + 1}
myclosey(1..3);
```

I expect 1 to be added to every element in the intrange. Instead, 1 is just added to the end of intrange,
so output is

```
[1,2,3,1]
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IntRange](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/IntRange.html) is a list. So the plus operator appends an element to the list. The closure is being called on the range itself, not each element of the range.

If you wanted to add one to all of the elements, you could do `(1..3).collect { it + 1 }`, or use the syntax that @dmahpatro suggested.

Comment: I added a reference to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are passing in a range to the closure so you have to do:

```
def myclosey = {items -> 
    items*.plus(1) //Spread on the range
}
assert myclosey(1..3) == [2, 3, 4]
```